# How to pass correctly object using redirectToRoute?

Tags: symfony

This is my simple code

```
class LuckyController extends Controller
{
    public function taskFormAction(Request $request)
    {
        $task = new Task();
        //$task->setTask('Test task');
        //$task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow noon'));

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
            ->add('task', TextType::class)
            ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save'))
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $task = $form->getData();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('task_ok', array('task' => '123'));
        }

        return $this->render('pre.html.twig', array('pre' => print_r($task, true), 'form' => $form->createView()));
    }

    public function taskOKAction(Task $task)
    {
        return $this->render('ok.html.twig', array('msg' => 'ok', 'task' => print_r($task, true)));
    }
}
```

and this line

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('task_ok', array('task' => '123'));
```

makes redirection to taskOKAction, but it lets me just send parameters by URL (?task=123).

I need to send object $task to taskOKAction to print on screen what user typed in form.

How can I do that? I've already red on stackoverflow before asking that the good solution is to store data from form (e.g. in database or file) and just pass in parameter in URL the ID of object. I think it's quite good solution but it adds me responsibility to check if user didn't change ID in URL to show other object.

What is the best way to do that?

Best regards,
L.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [parameter converter](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) and **annotate the route properly**.

Something like (if you use annotation for routes)

```
/**
 * @Route("/task/ok/{id}")
 * @ParamConverter("task", class="VendorBundle:Task")
 */
public function taskOKAction(Task $task)
```

You can also omit the `@ParamConverter` part if parameter is only one and if is type hinted (as in your case)

Comment: I use routing.yml. I tried to do your solution so I wrote:
`path: /task/ok/{task}` in routing
next, I changed code to
`return $this->redirectToRoute('task_ok', array('task' => $task));`
to transmit object and I got
`Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given`
:(
I added also
`@ParamConverter("task", class="AppBundle:Entity:Task")`
before taskOK Action.

Comment: don't pass the object, just the id

Answer (score 0):

From your form action you can do it without actual 302 redirect:

```
public function taskFormAction(Request $request)
{
    $task = new Task();
    //$task->setTask('Test task');
    //$task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow noon'));

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('task', TextType::class)
        ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save'))
        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        $task = $form->getData();
        return $this-taskOKAction($task)
    }
}
```

This is perfectly legal, and your frontend colleague will thank you for lack of the redirects.

Comment: how do you do validation and register to database like this ?

Comment: @t-n-y I copied some context code from question into my answer for clarity.

Comment: it's wrong, he don't want to render the 'ok' template before the form is submitted, he want the 'pre' template

Comment: Thanks but this solution lets for user refresh the form with resending entire date from form. I want to avoid this and have separated url to show "success" message. @t-n-y  do you know any improvement for this solution?